# IE8 Min-Width & Absolute Positioning issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css-position, css

I have a drop down menu who's trigger is a user name that can be of variable length. Inside the drop down there are buttons. To make the design look good when a user's name is really long I made the buttons inside the drop down width: 100%, and for it to look good when a user's name is very short I set a min-width.

Everything works great in every browser except IE8.

In this jsfiddle I've simplified the code and the drop down is always "on". I've also done two versions, one with a long name and one with a short name.

If you view it in IE8 the dropdown shifts over to the side incorrectly when a user's name is very short. It seems like when you set a min-width on an absolutely positioned element, IE8 doesn't like it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ntS3t/

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WrXas/2/

I added this to **.fs-top-nav li** so that the top level menu item doesn't wrap and break to the next line

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

I added these to **.fs-top-nav li > a** since the min-width made more sense to be on the top level item. I also center aligned it for better visual appearance.

```
min-width: 147px;
text-align: center;
```

I REMOVED this line from **.fs-top-nav .fs-top-nav-profile .fs-top-nav-drop**. I believe this is what was causing the weird placement of the drop down div.

```
min-width: 147px;
```

Comment: Mind you, there's one slight difference which is the top level item does not shrink to fit exactly the user name, however the length of the user name will rarely be that short and it does (arguably) look better aesthetically. I wonder what the root cause of that IE8 issue was... weird given that it works in IE7. Anyhow, thanks again.